# Find Distinct Column Names From Multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, set

I am trying to find only the unique column names from three different dataframes. The result should be columns 'A' and 'F'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('BCDE'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('CDEF'))

unique_list = np.unique(df1.columns, df2.columns, df3.columns)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Why would the result not just be A and F? B is unique between df2 and df3 but not df1 and E is unique between df1 and df2 but not df2 and df3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need symmetric difference which is nothing but union - intersection

```
a, b, c = df1.columns, df2.columns, df3.columns
(a | b | c).difference(a & b & c)
# Index(['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Shouldn't the answer only be A and F? B,C,D,E are in combinations of either dataframes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use numpy use [`intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html#numpy.intersect1d).

```
np.intersect1d(np.intersect1d(df1.columns, df2.columns), df3.columns)
array(['C', 'D'], dtype=object)
```

Or in pure python:

```
set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns).intersection(df3.columns)
{'C', 'D'}
```

Comment: @Starbucks I'm assuming you actually want the intersection of the set of column names. What exactly do you mean by the unique column names? Names that only appear in one dataframe? That would be the diff or {'A', 'F'}

Comment: Not the downvoter, but OP expects `['A', 'B', 'E', 'F']` as the output (column names that are unique to each frame).

Comment: Yea. Unique was a poor description. @Vaishali was right in that they want the symmetric diff.